# Need help dynamically creating threads in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.Net 2010. I have a function that checks a database for requests and some of the requests can take several minutes to complete. I don't want it to queue up while requests are being processed, so I want to dynamically create new threads to run each new request so that they can be ran simultaneously. I was not sure if I should use threads, threadpools, background workers or something else. Any suggestions and sample code would be great. I can work with a simple example. This is all I have so far.

Thank You.

```
Imports System.Threading
Module Module1
Private trd As Thread
Sub Main()
    'START THREAD
    trd = New Thread(AddressOf command_loop)
    trd.IsBackground = True
    trd.Start()

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Function command_loop()
       'CREATE EXPORT FILE
    Try
        Dim f As FileInfo
        Dim export As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Dim arr_comment

        'DELETE OLD EXPORT FILE
        If File.Exists(export_path) Then
            File.Delete(export_path)
        End If

        'VERIFY OLD EXPORT FILE WAS DELETED
        If File.Exists(export_path) Then
            writeToLog("ERROR: Old export file for " & username & " was not able to be deleted")
        End If

        'GET USER FOLDER CRC
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(user_folder)
        Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        export = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(export_path, True)
        export.WriteLine("filepath, size, esize, date_mod_timestamp, timestamp, remote_filename, filestatus")

        For Each f In fiArr
            Try
                Using zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(user_folder & "\" & f.Name)
                    For Each e As ZipEntry In zip
                        If (zip.Comment IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (zip.Comment <> "") Then
                            arr_comment = Split(zip.Comment, ":")
                        End If

                        If arr_comment.length <> 3 Then
                            'FILE HAS AN INVALID COMMENT, SO DELETE IT.
                            zip.Dispose()

                            Try
                                writeToLog("Invalid zip file comment, deleting file " & user_folder & "\" & f.Name)
                                File.Delete(user_folder & "\" & f.Name)
                                writeToLog("Zip file successfully deleted")
                            Catch exx As Exception
                                writeToLog("Unable to delete invalid zip file")
                                writeToLog(exx.Message)
                            End Try
                            Continue For
                        End If

                        'CORRECT FILE PATH
                        Dim filepath = Replace(e.FileName, "/", "\\")

                        export.WriteLine(Chr(34) & filepath & Chr(34) & "," & e.UncompressedSize & "," & e.CompressedSize & "," & arr_comment(1) & "," & arr_comment(2) & "," & f.Name & "," & arr_comment(0))
                        Exit For
                    Next
                End Using
            Catch ex As IOException
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Catch ex As ZipException
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                Try
                    writeToLog("Invalid zip file, deleting file " & user_folder & "\" & f.Name)
                    File.Delete(user_folder & "\" & f.Name)
                    writeToLog("Zip file successfully delete")
                Catch e As Exception
                    writeToLog("Unable to delete invalid zip file")
                    writeToLog(e.Message)
                End Try
            End Try
        Next f
        export.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
End Module
```

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to narrow down what you're doing and ask a specific question. For example, the code in the `'DO SOMETHING` method can greatly impact the correct solution.

Comment: you should use all those above + `Task.Run`. But it is really depends on the end goal

Comment: Here is the code that needs to be loaded into the threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the thread pool for this type of a task. It's much lighter weight than spawning new threads and the background worker only supports one thread per worker.

```
Private Class MyArgs
    'add things for cancellation / storing results in here
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim args As New MyArgs()
    Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf DoThisSingleThing, New MyArgs)
End Sub

Private Sub DoThisSingleThing(state As Object)
    Dim args = CType(state, MyArgs)

    While Not args.Cancel

    End While

    args.Result = ...

    'If you need to update the UI afterward then invoke onto its thread.
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() OnComplete(args))
End Sub


Private Sub OnComplete(args As MyArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to work for me. When the function completes, does the thread terminate on it's own or do I have to end it?

Comment: The thread is part of the thread pool so it will go back into the pool to be used by the next piece of work. You shouldn't terminate or modify the threadpool threads.